# Accessing Java ThreadLocal object from a class other than where it was declared

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, thread-local

I'm declaring a ThreadLocal object and setting a value like below.

```
Public Class Blah {

private ThreadLocal<Set<Integer>> numberThreaLocalObj= new ThreadLocal<>();

  void setValue() {
    Set<Integer> numberSet = new HashSet<>();
    numberSet .add(1);
    threaLocalObj.set(numberSet) 
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to reference this *numberThreaLocalObj* variable outside of this class within the same thread?

I've found some code the seems to clear ALL the threadlocals, but I just need to clear this particular Threadlocal variable based on a condition.

Unfortunately this is a inherited technical design.

EDIT - SOLUTION FOUND as outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use the following code to identify the specific threadlocal object I'm interested in
Code is used from a previous post, which was answered by @lyaffe https://stackoverflow.com/users/509566/lyaffe

My thread local object in another class

```
 private ThreadLocal<Set<Integer>> numberSetTL = new NamedThreadLocal<>("MY_NAMED_TL_NAME");
```

I've slightly modified the code to remove a specific Name. The ThreadLocal being removed would have to be a Spring NamedThreadLocal object.

```
 private void cleanThreadLocals() {
        try {
            // Get a reference to the thread locals table of the current thread
            Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
            Field threadLocalsField = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("threadLocals");
            threadLocalsField.setAccessible(true);
            Object threadLocalTable = threadLocalsField.get(thread);

            // Get a reference to the array holding the thread local variables inside the
            // ThreadLocalMap of the current thread
            Class threadLocalMapClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap");
            Field tableField = threadLocalMapClass.getDeclaredField("table");
            tableField.setAccessible(true);
            Object table = tableField.get(threadLocalTable);

            // The key to the ThreadLocalMap is a WeakReference object. The referent field of this object
            // is a reference to the actual ThreadLocal variable
            Field referentField = Reference.class.getDeclaredField("referent");
            referentField.setAccessible(true);

            for (int i=0; i < Array.getLength(table); i++) {
                // Each entry in the table array of ThreadLocalMap is an Entry object
                // representing the thread local reference and its value
                Object entry = Array.get(table, i);
                if (entry != null) {
                    // Get a reference to the thread local object and remove it from the table
                    ThreadLocal threadLocal = (ThreadLocal)referentField.get(entry);
                    if(threadLocal instanceof NamedThreadLocal) {

                        if("MY_NAMED_TL_NAME".equalsIgnoreCase(threadLocal.toString())) {
                            threadLocal.remove();
                            LOG.debug(tlName + " - ThreadLocal found and removed.");
                        }

                }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // We will tolerate an exception here and just log it
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it is a threadlocal is irrelevant. You're asking: Can I access a private field from another class?

The answer is: Not really. If you have the instance of Blah that you want to access this field for (it's a non-static field; therefore, there is one threadlocal for every instance of Blah), you can use java.lang.reflection:

```
Field f = Blah.class.getDeclaredField("numberThreaLocalObj");
f.setAccessible(true);
ThreadLocal<?> t = f.get(someInstanceOfBlah);
t.set(null);
```

would do it, once you add the appropriate exception guards.

Answer (score 0):

You can Have ThreadLocal variable as Static in a class and access it globally throughout your application. Example from official Spring docs

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue-examples/blob/00e1930be9d8c056f654c685e01eaa2ce49f0beb/retwisj/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/samples/retwisj/RetwisSecurity.java#L26

Don't forget to clear ThreadLocal variable in ThreadLocalExecutor handler (using afterExecute() which will execute after Thread is released to ThreadPool ) as shown in section 5.1 of below link:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal